# Modify images_upload_url dynamically on TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I'm trying to pass a parameter on the URL provided in `images_upload_url`.

This parameter changes depending on a field on the page. (A date input)

Is there any way I can set the value of `images_upload_url` dynamically on TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up removing and initializing TinyMCE again.

```js
function onChangeInput(){
    tinymce.remove();

    initEditor();
}
```

Not beautiful but it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies as well which can be created on the client and evaluated at server side.
The cookie value can then be considered in the api endpoint of the url defined in `images_upload_url`. With this approach you do not have to init the editor each time the url has been changed, only the cookie has to be set properly.